# Error in population %>% -cannot find function %>%

Tags: r, dplyr

```r
population <- read.csv("자치구단위 서울생활인구 일별 집계표.csv")

View(population)
str(population)
summary(population)

## install.packages('dplyr')
library('dplyr')

population %>%
   filter(between(기준일ID,
                    20200101,20210524)
         & 시군구명 == '서울시') %>%
```

I don't know why it doesn't run, and sometimes it runs, apparently randomly.
In this case, after run, I want to plus my variable '기준일ID'. but when I add this, it doesn't run again. Nothing change else before.. why

```
  select(시군구명,단기체류외국인인구수) %>%

  write.csv("C:/Users/haejo/OneDrive/바탕 화면/2021 1학기/빅데이터의과학적탐구 강의자료/a1541.csv"
            ,row.names=F,na=)


View(population1)
```

Comment: Your question is ininteligible. Please format it correctly, provide data with `dput(population)` , and reproducible example of your error

Comment: You should avoid examples with `View()` as they are usually not reproducible.
You should also avoid sharing code that was used iteractively but is actually irrelevant to your problem, such as `View(population)`,
`str(population)`, and
`summary(population)`

Answer (score 1):

We need to assign

```
population1 <- population %>%
    filter(between(기준일ID,
                20200101,20210524) & 시군구명 == '서울시') %>%

    select(시군구명,단기체류외국인인구수)
```